# Webstorm or Dart Editor. Which one is more mature

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-editor

In the beginning I want to mark that this is not a regular IDE vs IDE question, because Dart is still in it's infancy, and It's not about which is better but which is more recent.

There are only two decent Dart IDEs for now. Dart Editor and WebStorm. Which one has better feature-set for Dart development?

I know Dart Editor is made by people responsible for Dart language, but JetBrains(WebStorm) is much more mature and experienced.

Can anyone list the differences between those IDE's today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the official [site](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/)

> As of 1.11, Dart Editor is obsolete and no longer supported. We recommend using [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) to play with Dart and [WebStorm](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/webstorm/) to develop with Dart. For more information, see the [announcement](http://news.dartlang.org/2015/04/the-present-and-future-of-editors-and.html).

Also from [The present and future of editors and IDEs for Dart](http://news.dartlang.org/2015/04/the-present-and-future-of-editors-and.html)

> Another option is the [Eclipse plugin for Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/), which we continue to support. The Eclipse plugin, which currently shares most of its code with Dart Editor, is powered by the Dart Analysis Server.

Answer (score 7):

WebStorm team was working on Dart support for over a year now, getting regular feedback and assistance from the Dart team. So I believe that Dart support in WebStorm is quite mature.

The overall quality of code completion, navigation, code inspections (the same analyzer is used as in Dart editor) and quick fixes offered by WebStorm might make the difference. WebStorm has built-in debugger for Dart web and command line apps.

Moreover, WebStorm adds value by providing support for HTML and CSS (LESS, Sass, whatever you use) in your Dart project, while Dart editor doesn't. 
Have a look at the recent discussion in [Dartisans Google+ group](https://plus.google.com/+DonOlmstead/posts/R5kZcyCKx23).